# Logged response for Apple's Push Notifications servers with apn_on_rails?

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, push-notification

I'm using [apn_on_rails](https://github.com/PRX/apn_on_rails) to handle push notifications with my Rails app, but I'm not sure how to see what the response from Apple's servers are (for debugging purposes).

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no response for you to inspect.  `apn_on_rails` uses the "simple" format for communicating with APN over a streaming TCP socket -- if the connection is not severed, you assume success.

A little more [here in Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW4).